# Convert Negative Varchar, Null to Decimal in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert one of my measure column values having below from `varchar` to `decimal(20,3)`. The 3rd value is a null value without any space and to make you understand I enclosed with quotes. I have tried with `CAST` but `CAST` is not able to change datatype as having negative sign. But I want to keep negative value.

I tried using `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST` but that is not giving desired result. If anyone can help will be really helpful. I have tried below

```
CAST(COALESCE((NULLIF(SalesColumn,'')),'0') AS NUMERIC(20,12))

-992.0
0
```

Comment: Please give a concrete example of a row or value that isn't working for you, along with any error messages, the result you get, and the result you actually want. At present the phrase "is not able to change datatype as having negative sign" is too vague / ambiguous.

Comment: Using your statement with `'-992.0'` I get `-992.000000000000` - not clear on what your problem is

Comment: Okies so I want all this 3 to load into target Column where my Data type is Decimal(20,12).But using that statement individually working fine like converting -992 or converting NULL to Zero. But as a whole when I am trying to apply my logic upon entire column with CAST and CONVERT it is not working fine

Comment: You're not new - "it is not working fine" is not a useful comment. Define exactly what it does and how it does not meet your goal or expectations. We can't read your mind or see your screen. Does an error occur? If so, post ALL of the error message. If the result is not what you expect, then provide sample data, the output produced, and the output you expect. Suggest you clarify what datatype your column is since you use string constants.

Comment: I am getting Error converting data type varchar to numeric error. Though I have tried with all solutions given here but still getting this error. Thing is all expressions working fine with single value like only numbers or only null. But when it is trying to convert to Numeric with cast and coalesce and NULLIF i.e upon entire column it is throwing this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use SQL Server 2017 and `CAST` works just fine and maintains the "-"-sign, below is an example. Beware of the rounding, you might need to use `ROUND()` before converting it to `decimal(20,3)` by first converting it to a decimal with higher precision, using `ROUND()` and then casting it to `decimal(20,3)`.

Using `CAST` to `numeric` or `decimal` works just fine on `NULL` as well.

```
DECLARE 
     @Val1 VARCHAR(10) = '-992.123'
    ,@Val2 VARCHAR(10) = '-45678'
    ,@Val3 VARCHAR(10) = NULL
    ,@Val4 VARCHAR(10) = ''
    ,@Val5 VARCHAR(10) = '321'
    ,@Val6 VARCHAR(10) = ' '

SELECT ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF(A, '') as decimal(20,3)), 0)
FROM (
    VALUES (@Val1), (@Val2), (@Val3), (@Val4), (@Val5), (@Val6)
) Sub (A)
```

Which gives the result..

```
---------------------------------------
-992.123
-45678.000
0.000
0.000
321.000
0.000

(6 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `coalesce()` within `nullif()` to handle null value. Please look into below examples.

```
declare @var as varchar(50);
set @var=null;

select cast(COALESCE((NULLIF(coalesce(trim(@var),0),'')),'0') AS NUMERIC(20,12))
GO
```

```
| (No column name) |
| ---------------: |
|   0.000000000000 |
```

```
declare @var as varchar(50);
set @var='  ';

select cast(COALESCE((NULLIF(coalesce(trim(@var),0),'')),'0') AS NUMERIC(20,12))
GO
```

```
| (No column name) |
| ---------------: |
|   0.000000000000 |
```

```
declare @var as varchar(50);
set @var='- 992 ';

select cast(COALESCE((NULLIF(coalesce(trim(@var),0),'')),'0') AS NUMERIC(20,12))
GO
```

```
|  (No column name) |
| ----------------: |
| -992.000000000000 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bfe82ad18f826cfd65a3d2dfecffcca0)*

Comment: `coalesce(trim(@var), 0)` does [implicit conversion to int](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=f50f606375a1f9d7938df84bcae070be), so no magic in all other surrounding code.